# Recover from an unresponsive terminal

Tags: command-line

While trying to run `badblocks` on a hard drive riddled with errors it appears it crashed. Unfortunately, my terminal window is in an unresponsive state, here's a snip:

```
dave@home-theater:~⟫ sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda2                                                                                
Checking blocks 0 to 1953382399
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): ^C^C^C^Cdone, 23:14 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)

^C
^X
^Z
exit
quit
```

How do I get my hand out of this pickle jar? -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new terminal, and launch

```
xkill
```

Then click on the unresponsive one.
Read more about [xkill command](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.0/doc/html/xkill.1.html) , and:  [4 Ways to Kill a Process – kill, killall, pkill, xkill](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/4-ways-to-kill-a-process-kill-killall-pkill-xkill/) should help you too.

Good luck

Comment: I don't think this will work because I initiated the command via byobu over ssh.